# Create variable with quartile ranges based on condition

Tags: r

I have a numeric variable and I want to create a new categoric variable with the quantile ranges for the full dataset, but the quantile ranges should be calculated based on those observations that are controls.

The dataset looks like this:

| Case_Control | Age |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 25 |
| 1 | 36 |
| 0 | 45 |
| 0 | 12 |
| 1 | 24 |
| 1 | 27 |
| 0 | 38 |
| 1 | 55 |
| 0 | 82 |
| 1 | 21 |

I found how to do it manually (filtered first by `Case_Control`, then calculated the quantiles in age and finally created a new variable with `case_when()`), but I would like to have it automatic because I have to apply this to multiple datasets and variables.

The quantiles should be calculated for those that `Case_Control == 0`

I add here an example of the data:

```
# test data frame

Case_Control <- c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0)
Age <- c(25,36,45,12,24,27,38,55,82,21,34,56,69,78,25,16,17,54,59,28)
test <- as.data.frame(cbind(Case_Control, Age))

# Get quantils

controls <- test %>%
  dplyr::filter(Case_Control == 0)
summary(controls$Age)

# Here I get Q1 = 19 , Q2 = 27.5 , Q3 = 42.25

test <- test %>%
  mutate(age_group = case_when(
    Age <= 19 ~ 1,
    Age >= 19 & Age <= 27.5 ~ 2,
    Age >= 27.5 & Age <= 42.25 ~ 3,
    Age >= 42.25 ~ 4
  ))
```

Comment: The example you shared is a matrix not a data frame, but I assume you have actual dataframes? Also please share how you do it with one data frame so we can see your expected output.

Comment: @Sotos I have edited the example. `age_group`is the variable that I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get quartiles based on subset, then use *cut*:

```
#data
test  <- data.frame(Case_Control = c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0),
                    Age = c(25,36,45,12,24,27,38,55,82,21,34,56,69,78,25,16,17,54,59,28))

x <- quantile(test[ test$Case_Control == 0, "Age"], probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25))
x
#    0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
# 12.00 19.00 27.50 42.25 82.00

test$q <- cut(test$Age, breaks = x)

table(test$q)
# (12,19]   (19,27.5] (27.5,42.2]   (42.2,82] 
#       2           5           4           8
```